# PHP send file from db via mail

Tags: php, email, attachment

how is it possible to send a file, stored in a mysql db, via mail.
It worked when i tried to send it after downloading it to '../uploads/'.

```
if ($attachment != '') {
        $crlf = "\n";
        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
        $mime->setTXTBody($message);
        $mime->addAttachment('../uploads/file.xls');
        $body = $mime->get();
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
    } else {
        $body = $message;
    }

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host));
    $mail = $smtp->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
```

How can i make this

```
$mime->addAttachment('../uploads/file.xls');
```

read the file from the db ?

I would be thankfull for any hints.

Greetings

Alex

Comment: 1) Read the file content from the database. 2) Write to a temporary file. 3) Attach that file. 4) Send email. 5) Delete temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [documentation for the `Mail_Mime` PEAR package](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addattachment.php), the following should also work:

```
$mime->addAttachment(
    $fileContent,
    'application/octet-stream',
    $suggestedFileName,
    false                       # First parameter is content, not a filename.
);
```

Comment: Thank you Phylogenesis, i already tried it this way, but i didn't add the false parameter. Now it works like expected.

Comment: If this has helped you, please accept this answer by clicking the checkbox on the left.